# event dispatching thread

Tags: java

i tried to make a simple button inside a frame but button icon is not displayed properly my question is why??
2.) also why cant we put 
                `wingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
        new SwingDemo();
        }
            });`S inside SwingDemo(),or  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 3.) which statement  makes the edt thread??
please try to explain in simple terms otherwise more doubts will creep up.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class SwingDemo implements ActionListener {
SwingDemo() {
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("A Simple Swing Application");
    jfrm.setSize(275, 100);
    jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JButton jlab = new JButton(" Button ");
    jfrm.add(jlab);
    jfrm.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {       //2
    public void run() {
    new SwingDemo();
    }
    });
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    //jlab.setText("You selected " + ae.getActionCommand());
    //showStatus("You selected " + ae.getActionCommand());
```

}
}

Comment: How is the button icon _not displayed properly_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` it made at the initial stage of an application so that the creation of the UI occurs in the Event Dispatch Thread. It need to happen *before* the constructor or any subsequent method within the application is called. The thread created  is known as an [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: No. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` schedules a GUI creation task for execution on the EDT. As long as you make the `invokeLater` or `invokeWait` call, you don't need to worry about the actual "creation" of the EDT. This is managed by Swing itself.

Comment: sorry i did not understand your 1st reply , i mean invoke later and invoke and wait cant be used interchangeably??

Comment: Yes, typically `invokeLater` is used